# Excel: Move to right and then move down

Tags: excel

I'm doing an excel which the user will input in a better way their data.

I put an example of what that I want to achieve:
[Input data direction on the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nwmB.png)

So... The user starts inputting data at A2, then presses "Enter" button and the selected cell goes to B2. Once the user inputs data at B2 cell and presses enter again, the cursor moves to A3 and so on.
That's the movement that I want to implement to my sheet on excel.
A2 --> B2 --> A3 --> B3 --> A4 --> B4... each time the user presses "Enter" button.

I tried blocking all the other columns that aren't A and B column and with a macro use the following code:

```
'Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
'End Sub

'Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlDown
'End Sub
```

But when cursor reach to last active cell, if I press "Enter" button, then the cursor jumps to the first cell of the sheet.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your code changing the `MoveAfterReturnDirection` as is and add the following to the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Select
End Sub
```

Alternatively, don't touch the user's preferences and use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then Range("B" & Target.Row).Select
    If Target.Column = 2 Then Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Select
End Sub
```

In the worksheet

Comment: Yeah, I tried that simple thing but it doesn't work as is a excel property and It will be used on another computer. There will be a simple manner of do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to inform your users of the option? rather than force them into something they may not want?

Comment: I think via programatically using VBA it could be possible, I'm researching about that possibility, hope I can get anything useful. By the way, getting the last active cell I can move the cursor at the desired position.I Keep searching and playing.

Comment: You could set the `MoveAfterReturnDirection` to `xlToRight`, then use a Worksheet.Change event in column `B` to select the proper cell in column `A`

Comment: I used that, but when I reach the last active cell my selection restarts and jumps to the beginning of the sheet, A1$1 cell.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! That's the behaviour that I wanted at the excel sheet. ;)